# Send email using PHP PEAR but unable to authenticate to smtp server

Tags: php, email, authentication, smtp, pear

I am trying to send an automated email for notification from my web page.

Here's my code :

```
    include 'Mail.php';
    include 'Mail/mime.php' ;
    $text = 'Text version of email';
    $html = '<html><body>HTML version of email</body></html>';
    $file = 'bg.jpg';
    $crlf = "\n";

    $hdrs = array(
                  'From'    => 'myuser@myhost.com',
                  'Subject' => 'Test mime message function'
                  );
    $mime = new Mail_mime($crlf);

    $mime->setTXTBody($text);
    $mime->setHTMLBody($html);
    $mime->addAttachment($file, 'image/jpeg');

    $isi = $mime->get();
    $hdrs = $mime->headers($hdrs);

    $host = "myhost.com";
    $port = "587";
    $SMTPSecure="tls";
    $username = "myuser@myhost.com";
    $password = "mypass";

    $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', array('host' => $host,'port' => $port, 'auth' => true, 'debug' => true,
            'username' => $username, 'password' => $password, 'SMTPSecure'=>$SMTPSecure));
    $mail = $smtp->send('myOtherUser@myhost.com', $hdrs, $isi);

    if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
           $msg="<p>error = " . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>";
    }
```

It works perfectly when I test it in my localhost (*XAMPP for Windows 1.7.3, PHP version 5.3.1*).
But after I upload it on my server (*XAMPP for Linux 1.6.5a, PHP version 5.2.5*) it won't work.
Here's the debug result :

```
DEBUG: Recv: 220 SR-HO-MX01.myhost.com Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Wed, 4 Mar 2015 15:57:26 +0700
DEBUG: Send: EHLO localhost

DEBUG: Recv: 250-SR-HO-MX01.myhost.com Hello [114.4.68.107]
DEBUG: Recv: 250-SIZE 10485760
DEBUG: Recv: 250-PIPELINING
DEBUG: Recv: 250-DSN
DEBUG: Recv: 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
DEBUG: Recv: 250-STARTTLS
DEBUG: Recv: 250-AUTH GSSAPI NTLM
DEBUG: Recv: 250-8BITMIME
DEBUG: Recv: 250-BINARYMIME
DEBUG: Recv: 250 CHUNKING
```

I tried to change the port into 465 and set `$SMTPSecure` as *ssl* but still doesn't work, with the same debug result.

What should I check to repair this?

OpenSSL support setting in my server is already enabled.

Here's the debug result from my localhost

```
DEBUG: Recv: 220 SR-HO-MX02.myhost.com Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Wed, 4 Mar 2015 21:26:09 +0700
DEBUG: Send: EHLO localhost

DEBUG: Recv: 250-SR-HO-MX02.myhost.com Hello [223.255.230.52]
DEBUG: Recv: 250-SIZE 20971520
DEBUG: Recv: 250-PIPELINING
DEBUG: Recv: 250-DSN
DEBUG: Recv: 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
DEBUG: Recv: 250-STARTTLS
DEBUG: Recv: 250-AUTH GSSAPI NTLM
DEBUG: Recv: 250-8BITMIME
DEBUG: Recv: 250-BINARYMIME
DEBUG: Recv: 250 CHUNKING
DEBUG: Send: STARTTLS

DEBUG: Recv: 220 2.0.0 SMTP server ready
DEBUG: Send: EHLO localhost

DEBUG: Recv: 250-SR-HO-MX02.myhost.com Hello [223.255.230.52]
DEBUG: Recv: 250-SIZE 20971520
DEBUG: Recv: 250-PIPELINING
DEBUG: Recv: 250-DSN
DEBUG: Recv: 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
DEBUG: Recv: 250-AUTH GSSAPI NTLM LOGIN
DEBUG: Recv: 250-8BITMIME
DEBUG: Recv: 250-BINARYMIME
DEBUG: Recv: 250 CHUNKING
DEBUG: Send: AUTH LOGIN

DEBUG: Recv: 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
DEBUG: Send: redacted

DEBUG: Recv: 334 redacted
DEBUG: Send: redacted

DEBUG: Recv: 235 2.7.0 Authentication successful
DEBUG: Send: MAIL FROM:<myuser@myhost.com>

DEBUG: Recv: 250 2.1.0 Sender OK
DEBUG: Send: RCPT TO:<myuser@myhost.com>

DEBUG: Recv: 250 2.1.5 Recipient OK
DEBUG: Send: DATA

DEBUG: Recv: 354 Start mail input; end with <CRLF>.<CRLF>
DEBUG: Send: MIME-Version: 1.0
From: myuser@myhost.com
Subject: Test mime message function
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
    boundary="=_b2d99c906044c6425cf57f0c2c27b840"

--=_b2d99c906044c6425cf57f0c2c27b840
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
    boundary="=_ec04c97876af188028fad4b88c471128"

--=_ec04c97876af188028fad4b88c471128
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="ISO-8859-1"

Text version of email
--=_ec04c97876af188028fad4b88c471128
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Content-Type: text/html; charset="ISO-8859-1"

<html><body>HTML version of email</body></html>
--=_ec04c97876af188028fad4b88c471128--

--=_b2d99c906044c6425cf57f0c2c27b840
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Type: image/jpeg;
 name="bg.jpg"; 
Content-Disposition: attachment;
 filename="bg.jpg"; 

    /9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAgAAZABkAAD/7AARRHVja3kAAQAEAAAAZAAA/+4ADkFkb2JlAGTAAAAAAf/b
[....]
--

.


dc
DEBUG: Recv: 250 2.6.0 <98090985-136c-4479-9cdc-63b43c6f5042@SR-HO-MX01.sariroti.com> [InternalId=47017006989399] Queued mail for delivery
DEBUG: Send: QUIT

DEBUG: Recv: 221 2.0.0 Service closing transmission channel
```

Update :
I tried to send email using gmail user from my server and it works. So I think the problem is with my host and port. But how can I check it?

Comment: do you get actual error messages? how does the debug log look on your local machine?

Comment: Hi cweiske, thx for the respond. I added the debug log from my local machine. The `$mail->getMessage()` part returns "unable to authenticate to smtp server"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, finally I change my method using PHPMailer and everything can work normally.. Still don't know the problem with PEAR though..

Answer (score 0):

`Net/SMTP.php` supports STARTTLS only if you're on PHP 5.1.0+ (which you are) and if the openssl extension is loaded:

```
    if ($tls && version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.1.0', '>=') &&
        extension_loaded('openssl') && isset($this->_esmtp['STARTTLS']) &&
        strncasecmp($this->host, 'ssl://', 6) !== 0) {
```

You say SSL is enabled, but please run a script on your server that contains the following:

```
<?php var_dump(extension_loaded('openssl')); ?>
```

RUn it in the same way you start the mail sending. It should output `boolean(true)`.

Comment: I tried to use the if statement like you post, but even in my localhost, it always not pass the if statement. Can you explain what is `$tls`, `$this->_esmtp['STARTTLS'] `and `strncasecmp($this->host, 'ssl://', 6) !== 0` ?

Comment: the `var_dump(extension_loaded('openssl'));` result is `bool(true)`